# Multiple Windows in Tkinter (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

So, for an assignment that I am supposed to do for my programming course, I ran into a bit of an issue. We never really went through how to create child windows // secondary windows, and for some reason the things I add in the first window are not showing up?...

So far my code looks like:

```
from Tkinter import*

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.button1 = Button(self, text="Create new window", command=self.New_Window)
        self.button1.pack(fill=BOTH)

    def New_Window(self):
        win = Toplevel(self)
        win.title("New Window")
        etiquette1 = Label(root, text = "Text shenanigans")
        etiquette1.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main = Window(root)
    main.mainloop()
```

Also, another question is how can I name the first window? It's just called "tk" by default, but if I try to do something like the example below, it does not work.

```
self.__init__.title("Main Window")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument when creating widgets is the "parent" -- the widget into which the new widget goes.  If you want a label to be in the `Toplevel`, make the `Toplevel` be the parent:

```
etiquette1 = Label(win, ...)
```

To set the title of the window, call the `title` method:

```
root.title("This is the root window")
...
win.title("This is the second window")
```

Comment: I mainly meant that button1 does not show up in the original window. The window shows up, but the button that is supposed to trigger the second window opening does not show up, even though it is packed.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The root.title("This is the root window") worked just fine. But the button does still not appear in the first window. The button1 thingy

Comment: Actually, I am retarded :) Thanks for the help guys. It was written as 'self.button1 = Button(self, text="Create new window", command=self.New_Window)' while it should have been 'self.button1 = Button(root, text="Create new window", command=self.New_Window)'